# Wordpress sub_menu_page on custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I would love to add a sub menu page on my custom post type called "vouchercodes", but everytime I click on this item in the menu I get "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page."

I found some articels that "should" work:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63202/how-to-add-a-sub-menu-page-to-a-custom-post-type

But none of those worked for me. I'm sure that I use an full administrator account and I haven't recived any error's in my error logs.

The code I use:

```
function sens_admin_add_submenus(){
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=vouchercodes', 'Custom Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', 'vouchercodes_settings', 'My_Custom_Callback');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'sens_admin_add_submenus');
```

And my simpel callback function:

```
function My_Custom_Callback(){
    echo "<h1>Welcome to my awsome setting's page</h1>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Answer** Fix from [ishio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311631/ishio):

Change `admin_init` to `admin_menu`

Comment: Have you tried `admin_menu` instead of `admin_init`?

Comment: Wow, I did not even realize that I used `admin_init`, Using `admin_menu` instead works correctly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ishio add your comment as answer or matthew Brandenburg delete the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the add_action call from `admin_init` to `admin_menu` will correct this.